# Trying to create an excelfile that can be downloaded on my site

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to write to an excel file in PHP that a user on the site will be able to download. 
I have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ULDJ5LfdwU

The problem I'm running into is that the file won't open with the data on it.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadSheet\IOFactory;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $ticket = $_POST['ticket'];



      $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

      $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

      $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

      header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

      header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="result.xlsx"');

      $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
      $writer->save('php://output');
    }

     ?>

    <form class="" action="" method="POST">

      <p><input type="text" name="ticket" placeholder="Enter Data..."></p>
      <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="VALUE"></p>


    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error Messages:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNFcq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can safe your file on the server

```
$writer->save($path);
```

And make a link to the file after that.